# Is there a way to anticipate and prevent an OOM exception?

Tags: android, exception, out-of-memory, inputstream

I get an input stream from a `HttpUrlConnection` object. The http response is a JSON-formatted web page whose size is larger than 50 Mb.

By getting this input stream into a string variable, my app ends up by crashing with a fatal exception `OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51096576 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 47MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 244303608, growth limit 268435456`.

Seemingly, the app is unable to allocate the required memory for this string.

Is there a way to anticipate an `OOM` exception? (say for example, when the input stream will almost eat up all of the heap. At least, I can alter the behaviour of my app when this is about to happen)

Comment: *The http response is a JSON-formatted web page whose size is larger than 50 Mb.* dear lord. Why?

Comment: Same question here???

Comment: A concrete example :
If you are familiar with Navitia, here is a link to get nearby stop schedules for public transportation in some region in Paris. Results are so numerous that the size of the page exceeds 50Mb. https://api.navitia.io/v1/coverage/2.3449645;48.8620508/coord/2.3449645;48.8620508/stop_schedules?count=1000&distance=500&max_date_times=10 (you may need a token to send such http request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to anticipate an OOM exception ?

No, sorry.

> say for example, when the inputStream will almost eat up all of the heap

That is not the cause of an `OutOfMemoryException`. You get an `OutOfMemoryException` when you try to allocate a block of memory and there is no free block of memory big enough for your request.

In your case, you have plenty of free heap space. You are asking to allocate a huge block.

> By getting this input stream into a string variable

That is the source of your difficulty. Use a streaming JSON parser (Jackson and Gson both have streaming modes IIRC) and use the JSON in small pieces.

Comment: Ah ok. So heap is a fragmented memory !
In fact, I use the JSONObject class for JSON parsing, that's why I need to extract a string from the input stream

Comment: @MahmoudMasmoudi: "I use the JSONObject class for JSON parsing" -- don't do that. If you need something that is in the Android SDK, use `JsonReader`, as that is a streaming JSON parser. You are not going to be able to use `JSONObject` reliably for anything nearly that large.